# Association in rails not working

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, ruby-on-rails-4

I have bit complicated model design with many associations among themselves. 
Here is model design

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :records
has_many :sources
has_many :record_type_student
has_many :record_type_employee
has_many :record_type_other

validates :email, presence: true

end
```

Souces Model

```
class Source < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user

 has_many :records
 has_many :record_type_student
 has_many :record_type_employee
 has_many :record_type_other

end
```

Record Model

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :source

 has_many :record_type_student
 has_many :record_type_employee
 has_many :record_type_other

end
```

RecordTypeStudent Model

```
  class RecordTypeStudent < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :record
 belongs_to :user
belongs_to :source

end
```

Similar Model for other two RecordTypeOther and RecordTypeEmployee

I can save data properly and I checked every `recordtype*` table contains record_id in it and now I am trying to access data using `includes`. Here is what I am trying to query

```
 @records = Record.includes(:record_type_stduents, :record_type_others, :record_type_employees).where(User.find_by_email(params[:user].to_s).id).all;
```

but I get only records fields in return not data after joining

Here is generated query

```
 Record Load (1.9ms)  SELECT `records`.* FROM `records` WHERE `records`.`user_id` =  1    RecordTypeStudent Load (7.9ms)  SELECT `record_type_students`.* FROM  `record_type_students` WHERE `record_type_students`.`record_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25)  RecordTypeOther Load (2.4ms)  SELECT `record_type_others`.* FROM `record_type_students`    WHERE `record_type_students`.`record_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25)  RecordTypeEmployee Load (2.0ms)  SELECT `record_type_employees`.* FROM `record_type_employees` WHERE `record_type_employees`.`recordt_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25)
```

Here is when I try to pull from User model

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Relation#all is deprecated. If you want to eager-load a relation, you can call #load (e.g. `Post.where(published: true).load`). If you want to get an array of records from a relation, you can call #to_a (e.g. `Post.where(published: true).to_a`). (called from irb_binding at (irb):15)

User Load (3.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `records` ON `records`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` WHERE `users`.`user_id` = 1
```

Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `records` ON `records`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` WHERE `users`.`user_id` = 1 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `records` ON `records`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` WHERE `users`.`user_id` = 1

Comment: `among themselves` - you meant `self referential` joins?

Comment: no, associations like I mentioned in each model no self referential

Comment: but did you get the problem in the code or I have not explained well here...

Comment: Just looking for you now!

Comment: i think issue is in query. can you please paste your generated sql query ?

Comment: Right so you're trying to find all the record types for a paricular user?

Comment: Updated, I am trying to find all record of particular user ...so it could be type "student", "other" or etc

Comment: Why don't you just pull from the User model & join the records model?

Comment: I tried but I did not work and throws error

Comment: Updated you can see what it throws

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll be best using [STI (single table inheritance)](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance):

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :students, class: "User::Student"
   has_many :employees, class: "User::Employee"
   has_many :other, class: "User::Other"
end

#app/models/users/student.rb
Class Student < Record
end

#app/models/record.rb
Class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

This will give you the following fields:

```
#users
id | user | attributes | created_at | updated_at

#records
id | type | user_id | other | record | attributes | created_at | updated_at
```

This will allow you to call:

```
user = User.find params[:id]
user.students # -> pulls records with type == "Student"
```

Comment: Thanks alot I will try this and let you know how it works but one question Student, Other etc Model will not have any association defined in them

Comment: I don't think they will need it (although I may be wrong). An STI basically inherits from the parent models; meaning you should be able to keep a central association; although I can be wrong on this

Comment: One question, I was reading about STI but could not understand how to generate models like Student which are inherited from Record...any command or how I would add fields in student Model

Comment: Sorry I'll update my answer for you! There's a great tutorial here: http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/45-use-sti-and-polymorphic-model-for-multiple-uploads